# How precise should an absolute error be?

Tags: numerical-methods, rounding-error

While adding approximate numbers, our result must be as precise as the *least precise number* that was given to us.
For instance, $101+1.001+1.0≈103$ because the number with the least precision viz., $101$, is correct to the nearest unit.

But what about when evaluating errors? Suppose $2/3$ is approximated to $0.6667$. Then the absolute error would be $|2/3-0.6667|$. But this value is $0.00003333333...$, which, according to our rules, we must approximate to $0.0000$ (as precise as $0.6667$).

This is certainly not right.

Comment: I think you can see a non zero difference only if you give more precision. For example $|2/3 - 0.6667000|$.

Comment: But why would I write 2/3≈0.66670000? It is incorrect.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, $0.6667 = 0.66670000$, so $2/3 \approx 0.26667$ and $2/3 \approx 0.26667000$ are identical statements. The point is that $\approx$ is ambiguous, as well as the intent of adding $000$. If you want to avoid ambiguities you can write $2/3 = 0.6667\pm 10^{-4}$

Comment: But 0.6667 and 0.6667000 aren't the same. One is more precise than the other. And my point was that 2/3 when rounded to the nearest 0.0000001, gives 0.6666667, and not 0.6667000.

Comment: It means that you consider that $2/3 \approx 0.6667$ implicitly means that $2/3 = 0.6667\pm 10^{-4}$. If this is so, the only thing you can write is $|2/3 - 0.6667|\le 10^{-4}$.

Comment: Your rounding scheme is highly unusual. What kind of floating point representation are you using? If you are using the standard floating point representation (probably with base 10), then $1.0$ has precision $2$ and $103.001$ should be rounded to $100$. Also $0.00003333333..$ rounded to $4$ decimal places is $0.00003333$ not $0.0000$.

Comment: You rounded it to 4 significant figures, not 4 decimal places. Rounded to 4 decimal places means rounded to the nearest 10^-4. The nearest 10^-4 to it is 0.0000.

Comment: Well, maybe you are about the terminology, but still you cannot round $0.00003333$ to $0.000$, at least not in the standard floating point representation.

Comment: When someone tells you to round 19 to the nearest ten, would you not say 20? And what would 4 rounded to the nearest ten be? Would it not be 0?

Comment: Then what is 4 rounded to the nearest ten?

Comment: Any nonzero decimal floating point number is represented as $\text{sig}\times 10^{\text{exp}}$, where $|\text{sig}| \geq 1$. Precision is the number of digits in the significant $\text{sig}$. Rounding it is just dropping least significant  digits in $\text{sig}$ in order to adjust precision. You are doing something else and call this "rounding". But this has nothing to do with the rounding of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

By precision rule $0.0000 \approx 0$ up to the 4th decimal place. However $0.0000 \ne 0$ since we don't know (or can't measure) the following digit

The best you can say is

$$ 0 < |2/3 - 0.6667| < 0.0001 $$

Or the error is somewhere on the order of $10^{-5}$

Comment: $0.0000\neq 0$? huh? $\sum_{i=1}^4 0\times 10^{-i}\neq 0$?

Comment: Perhaps this question better belongs in SE Physics. Mathetically this makes no sense. However the rule of significant figures apply here and we implicitly assume that $0.0000$ is a very small number rounded down to the 4th decimal place.

Comment: $0.0000 \approx 10^{-4} + (10^{-5})x $ with $x$ being an unknown value

Comment: As Gribouillis says, the thing is that $\approx$ is not well defined. It is probably a question of definition.  E.g. Yves Daoust uses a definition for $=$ which is not the one I know (probably by ignorance).

Comment: The $=$ in this context does not mean absolute equality, since there's always an implicit error. As such $=$ and $\approx$ are interchangeable.

Comment: This whole thing will make mathematicians upset. All I'm saying is the measurement $0.0000$ as it's written down does not equal absolute $0$ (in the mathematical sense), only an infinitesimally small number (smaller than $10^{-4}$) that's indistinguishable from $0$ due to lack of precision.

Answer (score 1):

Thats right, with an absolute error of $0.0001$,

$$\left|\frac23-0.6667\right|=0.0000$$

Comment: This implies $0.0000\neq 0$. Do you confirm??!

Comment: $|2/3-0.6667|=0.00000333333....=0.0000=0$ mmh... I don't understand...

Comment: @anderstood  Equality is understood as "to less than $0.0001$". So all numbers in $(-0.0001,0.0001)$ are undistinguishable.

Comment: But is it an implicit definition of equality, implied by the number of zeroes in $0.0000$?

Comment: @anderstood: we are in the context of a known absolute error.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, $0.666667=0.6666670000$. Your confusion probably comes from the fact that you *implicitly* think that $0.6666670000$ is more accurate, presumably because of the use of [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) in physics.

Comment: I'd say this is more of a physics question than a math question, from the way it is framed. Everything is assumed to have an implicit error $0.6667$ and $0.6667000$ maybe the same value, but one is more precise than the other.

Comment: Note that in this context, $0.6667000$ is more *precise* than $0.6667$, although they have the same *accuracy*

Comment: @Dylan I agree, if it is clear that the digits are significant figures. What makes things confusing, I think, is that it is not explicitly said. Probably some consider that using `\approx` implies that use. Anyway, apart from semantics, I think/hope everybody is on the same line...

Comment: These two have the same accuracy, not precision.